# How to add click action on label in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, ios, monodevelop

I searched a while but can't figure out how to add an action on a label with MonoDevelop.
Normally you have the choice between, action, outlet.. But with a label it's only available to add an outlet.

So here my question is it possible just to add an event when the users clicks on the label? If yes, how can you do it?

(My backup plan is juist to change the labels into buttons (with the same look and feel) but want to stay with my labels .. )

thx in advance

Comment: i don't think this is related to iOs?

Comment: it's an app that has to be developed for ios, so my views are made with xcode. That's why I added the ios-tag.

Comment: So you are creating UILabel on Xcode?

Comment: Yes I am ! And I added an outlet to be able to change the text during the 'life' of the app, but I wanted him to be able to check a touch_event too, but now I see that I don't have the possibility to chose for 'action'

Comment: Ok. Check the answer, might be that is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `UILabel` you can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` to achieve this-

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)];
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

//Now you can define action in myAction method.

Hope it clears.

Comment: Your uitabgesture hint was everything I needed ! In xcode I could drag an uittabgesture to my labels and there add everything I needed to control if the label was clicked. Thanks a lot !